# ASP impersonation fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have programmatically impersonated a WINDOWS NT account to access a network resource. I have set my web.config to allow impersonation.

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Windows" />


<identity impersonate="true" />
</system.web>
```

I have also verified the user name after impersonation using

```
      System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

But when I tried to create a directory, it is throwing Unauthorized access exception. The impersonated account has full access at the destination folder. Do you see any issues ?

Comment: In the end - what is the identity of the website application pool? This is one used for accessing network resources.

Comment: It is hard to see what exactly you "verified the user name after impersonation". There is should be 3 names involved (incoming user's name, app pool identity user name and account name you are impersonating with code). Clarifying will make question better.

Comment: I have not done any configuration at IIS level. The identity is set to application pool identity. This problem even if I run from my development server

Comment: So you application pool identity should have access to you network resource.

Comment: Could you please explain the process a bit in detail ?

Comment: For the network access, you website identity is less important. It is application pool user that is checked. Try to changing it to some, for example, domain user and give access rights for the network resource for this specific user.

Comment: Then what is the whole idea behind asp.net impersonation ?

Comment: I just came across  something called delegation. It is required not only we impersonate but also need to trust the computer for delegation. Btw , a quick check ,  my project follows a  defined architecture where by I make reference of a class library to my mvc project. My impersonation code lies inside class library  project. Does it hurt in anyway ? (Meaning ,unable to reach the web.config of the MVC Project ??)